# Create an outlook link from an item

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I'm using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` to work with some public folders and their items.

I would like to create a `<a href="outlook://XXXX">View item</a>` link to a specific item (`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item`), but I can't figure out how to get it's path.

something like:

```
var theLink = 
   string.Format(@"<a href=""outlook://{0]"">Click here</a>", item.XXXX);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to not be possible anymore to due security.

Instead I created a link to Outlook Web Access instead.